# Passing a variable to reference instance attributes

Tags: python, class

Can someone explain what is happening in the function after the initialiser?

Specifically `other.row` and `other.column`. I have never seen this before and don't understand how you can pass a variable and use it to reference instance attributes.

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, row: int, column: int):
        self.column = column
        self.row = row

    def __add__(self, other):
        row = self.row + other.row
        col = self.column + other.column
        return Tile(row, col)
```

Comment: It's not a variable. It's just accessing the `row` attribute of the `other` object.

Comment: It's no different from `self.row`.

Comment: `other` is presumably another `Window` object. They both have `row` attributes, this is adding them together.

Comment: The `other` here can be a different class or its instance with attributes `row` and `column`.  Since Python is an object-oriented language, everything in it are objects, so `other` is also an object. Read more here - https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Comment: `x.y` is merely a way to reference the attribute named `y` of the object to which `x` refers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `return Window(row, col)`? It's odd that adding two Window objects would return a Tile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is an object from which you are calling the method, `other` is the second object. Typing `obj1 + obj2` will cause that python is looking for `__add__` dunder method in the `obj1` class. If he finds it, he takes as first argument `obj1(self)`, the second argument is `obj2(other)`. Then he takes the row value from obj1(called self) and row value from obj2(called other). Objects must have column and row variable, if one of them don't have it, an exception will be raised. The same goes for column